# Can't switch to back camera in Android WebView using PeerJs

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, peerjs

I've been trying to make a simple WebRTC app using Firebase Database and PeerJs that can switch cameras. I found one [tutorial](https://youtu.be/LkB9F-lGBrI) and it works properly, but I want to switch the camera between front and back which is not included in the tutorial.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    ...

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

    ...

</manifest>
```

CallActivity.java

```
import static android.view.View.GONE;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.UUID;

public class CallActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = CallActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final String CAMERA_FRONT = "user";
    private final String CAMERA_BACK = "environment"; // Tried to use it on navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {facingMode: camera}}) but it didn't work.

    private RelativeLayout layoutIncoming, layoutCall, layoutCallControl;
    private Button buttonReject, buttonAccept, buttonCall, buttonAudio, buttonVideo, buttonCamera;
    private EditText editTextCallName;
    private TextView textViewIncoming;

    private WebView webView;

    private String name;
    private String callerName;
    private boolean isPeerConnected = false;

    private DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("link_to_firebase_database").getReference("users");

    private boolean videoEnabled = true;
    private boolean audioEnabled = true;
    private String camera = CAMERA_FRONT;

    private String uniqueID;

    //== Overridden ==//

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call);

        layoutIncoming = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_layoutIncoming);
        layoutCall = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_layoutCall);
        layoutCallControl = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_layoutCallControl);

        buttonAccept = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_buttonAccept);
        buttonReject = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_buttonReject);
        buttonCall = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_buttonCall);
        buttonVideo = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_buttonVideo);
        buttonAudio = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_buttonAudio);
        buttonCamera = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_buttonCamera);

        editTextCallName = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_editTextCallName);
        textViewIncoming = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_textViewIncoming);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.activity_call_webView);

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("name")) {
            name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        }

        buttonCall.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            callerName = editTextCallName.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!callerName.isEmpty()) sendCallRequest();
        });

        buttonVideo.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            videoEnabled = !videoEnabled;
            callJsFunction("javascript:toggleVideo(\"" + videoEnabled + "\")");

            if (videoEnabled)
                buttonVideo.setText("Video Off");
            else
                buttonVideo.setText("Video On");
        });

        buttonAudio.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            audioEnabled = !audioEnabled;
            callJsFunction("javascript:toggleAudio(\"" + audioEnabled + "\")");

            if (audioEnabled)
                buttonAudio.setText("Mute");
            else
                buttonAudio.setText("Unmute");
        });

        buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (camera.equals(CAMERA_FRONT)) camera = CAMERA_BACK;
            else camera = CAMERA_FRONT;

            switchCamera();
        });

        setupWebView();
    }

    //== Public ==//

    public void onPeerConnected() {
        isPeerConnected = true;
    }

    //== Private ==//

    private void setupWebView() {
        WebChromeClient client = new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
                runOnUiThread(() -> request.grant(request.getResources()));
            }
        };

        webView.setWebChromeClient(client);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(this), "Android");

        loadVideoCall();
    }

    private void loadVideoCall() {
        String filePath = "file:///android_asset/call.html";
        webView.loadUrl(filePath);

        WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                initializePeer();
            }
        };

        webView.setWebViewClient(client);
    }

    private void initializePeer() {
        uniqueID = getUniqueID();

        callJsFunction("javascript:init(\"" + uniqueID + "\")");

        usersRef.child(name).child("incoming").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Received incoming call!!!");
                onCallRequest(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void sendCallRequest() {
        if (!isPeerConnected) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You're not connected to internet. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        usersRef.child(callerName).child("incoming").setValue(name);
        usersRef.child(callerName).child("isAvailable").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                boolean isAvailable = snapshot.getValue() != null? snapshot.getValue(boolean.class): false;

                if (isAvailable) {
                    listenForConnectionID();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void onCallRequest(String caller) {
        if (caller == null) return;

        String incomingMessage = caller + " is calling...";
        textViewIncoming.setText(incomingMessage);

        buttonAccept.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            usersRef.child(name).child("connectionID").setValue(uniqueID);
            usersRef.child(name).child("isAvailable").setValue(true);

            layoutIncoming.setVisibility(GONE);
            switchToCallControls();
        });

        buttonReject.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            usersRef.child(name).child("incoming").setValue(null);
            layoutIncoming.setVisibility(GONE);
        });

        layoutIncoming.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void listenForConnectionID() {
        usersRef.child(callerName).child("connectionID").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.getValue() == null) return;

                switchToCallControls();
                callJsFunction("javascript:startCall(\"" + snapshot.getValue(String.class) + "\")");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void switchToCallControls() {
        layoutCall.setVisibility(GONE);
        layoutCallControl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void switchCamera() {
        Log.d(TAG, "switchCamera: " + camera);

        callJsFunction("javascript:switchCamera(\"" + camera + "\")");
    }

    private void callJsFunction(String functionString) {
        webView.post(() -> webView.evaluateJavascript(functionString, value -> Log.d(TAG, value)));
    }

    private String getUniqueID() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

call.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="./peerjs.js"></script>

        <video class="secondaryVideo" autoplay id="remoteVideo"></video>
        <video class="primaryVideo" autoplay muted id="localVideo"></video>

        <script src="./call.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

call.js

```
let localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo")
let remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo")

localVideo.style.opacity = 0
remoteVideo.style.opacity = 0

let peer

function init(userID) {
    peer = new Peer(userID)

    peer.on('open', () => {
        Android.onPeerConnected();
    })

    listen()
}

let localStream

function listen() {
    peer.on('call', (call) => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true
        }).then(function(mediaStream) {
            localStream = mediaStream

            localVideo.srcObject = localStream
            localVideo.style.opacity = 1

            call.answer(localStream)

            call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
                remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream
                remoteVideo.style.opacity = 1

                // Swap classes of localVideo and remoteVideo

                localVideo.className = "secondaryVideo"
                remoteVideo.className = "primaryVideo"
            })
        })
    })
}

function startCall(otherUserID) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true
    }).then(function(mediaStream) {
        localStream = mediaStream

        localVideo.srcObject = localStream
        localVideo.style.opacity = 1

        const call = peer.call(otherUserID, localStream)

        call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
            remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream
            remoteVideo.style.opacity = 1

            // Swap classes of localVideo and remoteVideo

            localVideo.className = "secondaryVideo"
            remoteVideo.className = "primaryVideo"
        })
    })
}

function toggleVideo(b) {
    if (b == "true") {
        localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true
    } else {
        localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false
    }
}

function toggleAudio(b) {
    if (b == "true") {
        localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true
    } else {
        localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false
    }
}

let camIndex = 0

function switchCamera() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function(devices) {
        var cameras = []

        devices.forEach(function(device) {
            'videoinput' === device.kind && cameras.push(device.deviceId)
        })

        console.log(cameras.length)

        if (camIndex == cameras.length - 1) {
            camIndex = 0
        } else {
            camIndex = camIndex + 1
        }

        var constraints = {
            video: {deviceId: {exact: cameras[camIndex]}},
            audio: true
        }

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(mediaStream) {
            localStream = mediaStream

            localVideo.srcObject = localStream

            console.log("camera switched to camIndex " + camIndex) // Only triggered when camIndex = 0
        })
    })
}
```

I assume that camIndex = 1 is a back camera but it gives this error message in the logcat

```
D/CallActivity: switchCamera: environment
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
D/CallActivity: null
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(97)] "2", source: file:///android_asset/call.js (97)
E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
W/ThreadPoolSingl: type=1400 audit(0.0:35101): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=19669 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c161,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/cr_VideoCapture: cameraDevice encountered an error
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotReadableError: Could not start video source", source: file:///android_asset/call.html (0)
D/CallActivity: switchCamera: user
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
D/CallActivity: null
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(97)] "2", source: file:///android_asset/call.js (97)
D/: PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
D/AudioTrack: stop(398): called with 62088 frames delivered
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(115)] "camera switched to camIndex 0", source: file:///android_asset/call.js (115)
W/.testapp_webrt: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/AudioManager: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
W/AudioManager: See the documentation of requestAudioFocus() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
```